# Can I load a serverless file using some yaml library?

Tags: yaml, serverless-framework

I am trying to load a serverless file using a yaml library to do some preprocessing:

```
const yaml = require('js-yaml');
const file = await fs.readFile(path, { encoding: 'utf8' });
const doc = yaml.load(file);
```

I am getting an error:

```
YAMLException: unknown tag !<!Ref> (26:42)
```

Because of this line:

```
S3_BUCKET: !Ref ComposerBucket
```

Is it possible to load serverless files into an object somehow? I'm thinking maybe serverless is using some particular schema that I need to define when loading, but I don't know.

```
const doc = yaml.load(file, { schema: 'serverless-framework' });
```

Do you have any idea how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution while browsing the serverless npm package source code:

```
const cloudformationSchema = require('@serverless/utils/cloudformation-schema');
const doc = yaml.load(file, { schema: cloudformationSchema });
```